# How to calculate the number of values of current selection which has repeated in older entries

Tags: count, powerbi, dax

I have below data model, which has two main fact tables.
[image]

It has below relationship as well.

- defect_report[IssueKey] = test_execution_summary[ExecutionDefect]
- test_cycle_details[cycleID] = test_Execution_summary[CycleID]]

So far I could filter my dataset based on the practice name, project name using slicers and from the latest release version using measures and visual filter. The CycleID column has the IDs starting from 1, where Last cycle ID receive the lower number and older cycles receive the larger numbers, because I am sorting my dataset from executed date in descending order.

[image]

Now I need to add another column which gives the count of bugs that has appeared in previous cycles. In this case, the GRR-1009 which is a bug in the second cycle is bug which has occurred in earlier cycle. So I need to have 1 for the second cycle name.

[image]

Appreciate if someone can help me to resolve this. Since I am new to Power BI, still it is kind of difficult to think from DAX perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the overall approach. Get a list of the bug IDs for the selected cycle. Use `REMOVEFILTERS` to remove the cycle context and get the count of IDs of previous cycles that are the same as the current.

Try (excuse any typos):

```
Earlier Bug count = 
  var bugIdsInThisCycle =
    CALCULATETABLE(
      DISTINCT('test_execution_summary'[ExecutionDefect]),
      'defect_report'[Issue Type] = "Bug"
    )
  var thisCycle = MIN('test_cycle_details'[cycleID])
  var result = 
    CALCULATE(
      DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK('test_execution_summary'[ExecutionDefect]),
      REMOVEFILTERS('test_cycle_details'),
      'test_execution_summary'[CycleID] > thisCycle &&
      'test_execution_summary'[ExecutionDefect] IN bugIdsInThisCycle
    )

  return COALESCE(result, 0)
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing, it worked... I still don't understand how to think from DAX perspective, cz sometimes it is evaluating row by row and sometimes it is returning a total value. In this, we use MIN function just to obtain the current cycle value as a single value right? It doesn't actually look for a minimum. REMOVEFILTERS is used to ignore the filters applied via slicers and visual filter?

Comment: It is always calculating row by row, and the total row is no different apart from there being no dimension(s) in-scope. Yes, `MIN` in `thisCycle` is almost the same as using `SELECTEDVALUE` ie get the current row dimension value. MIN/MAX is sometimes preferred over `SELECTEDVALUE` as the latter will not return anything if more than one value is found (like in the Total row). `REMOVEFILTERS` is used here to remove/break the current row context applied by the Dimension in that row `CycleName`, it would also remove any slicers/filters on that Dimension table. Hope this helps.